# PHP variable in loop refuses to increment

Tags: php

```
for($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++) {
  for($k = 0; $k < 8; $k++) {
    $ln = $k + 1;
    if(...) {
    //Code for table edges like row and col names
    //end code
    } else { //Other cases
      //switch statement, looks like
      switch($j) {
        case 2:
          $keyname = $ln.'_FAR_INT';
          break;
        ... //All cases are accounted for in this switch
      }
      foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        if(strpos($keyname, $key) !== false) {
          $cellVal = $key;
          break;
        } else {
          $cellVal = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Problem image]

So the problem here is that the variable `$ln` is stuck at 2 no matter what as soon as it hits a blank row. The first two columns have data from a database, and the third onwards have blanks in their relevant key/value pairs, so they're not returning `null`, but `&nbsp;`

If you notice, it gets to `2_FAR_INT`, then does that forever until it hits the next row.

I don't know why it does this and debugging it has been a painful endeavor.

Dataset: Looks like `{data: 1_FAR_INT, 2_FAR_INT, 3_FAR_INT, etc..., 1_TOTAL_BORN, 2_TOTAL_BORN, 3_TOTAL_BORN,...}`

Why does `$ln` refuse to increment appropriately to `$k + 1` in every single case no matter what I tell it to do?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/BzOlbSyC) the behaviour so the error is most likely in the `if`, `else` or `switch` statement (all of which you omitted)

Comment: Yep, agreed with @kingkero, working fine with a basic example, you need to include the stuff you have removed as that is probably the issue. http://3v4l.org/Tj0pM